# Sidekiq quickest way to loop through every record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, sidekiq, delayed-job, worker

I have a sidekiq job that I schedule to run every day at midnight. The job loops through every shop (user) in my database and runs the worker for each one. The more shops or users that my database gains, the slower this approach will be. I was wondering, is there a more efficient way to go about this?

Comment: Sidekiq or not, if you have a lot of records, then it's better to group them into small batches and process them. You can take a look at [this](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_in_batches)

Comment: To add to my above comment, you can then trigger a worker for each of those batch and adjust concurrency as per your specs.

Answer (score 0):

Doing any batch operations row by row won't scale well. The best approach is to re-write your Sidekiq Job to execute all the rows at once.  If you can provide more details on what you're trying to achieve, I'd be happy to help. :)

Comment: Not sure how I would execute them all at once. I have a sidekiq job that does a .each on a table and runs API calls on each record.

Comment: @kolbykskk is this an internal API or an external?

Comment: External, Shopify API

Comment: Can anyone help with this?

Comment: @kolbykskk send me the specifics via message and I'll take a look for you today!